# Is P(A and B) = P(B and A)?

Tags: probability

I was wondering if the following statement is true and if there are any times in which the following is not true:

Is the probability of A and B equal to the probability of B and A?

P(A and B) = P(B and A)?

Would it be suffice to show that they are equal based on P(A and B) representing the same intersection as P(B and A) on a venn diagram?

Comment: @TobyMak Perhaps you are considering $\mathbb P(A\mid B)$ and $\mathbb P(B\mid A)$ instead? Clearly for any sets $A,B$ the we have $A\cap B = B\cap A$...

Comment: Sorry, read the question wrong.

Comment: @Math1000 Ah okay, so P(A and B) is then equal to P(B and A), thanks a lot! I figured that was the case but I wanted to make sure, tried looking around and couldn't find an answer either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability of events $A$ and $B$ both occurring is the same as the probability of $B$ and $A$ both occurring. I know it seems almost silly and obvious when written like that.

This is denoted by $p(A\cap B) = p(B \cap A)$.

Note that this is quite distinct from the following two scenarios:

The probability of $A$ occurring if $B$ occurs is not necessarily the same as the probability of $B$ occurring if $A$ occurs. This has to do with conditional probability and the two probabilities are denoted $p(A|B) $ and $p(B|A) $ respectively.

Also, when there is a temporal (time) or sequential aspect involved, note that the probability of $A$ occurring, then $B$ is not necessarily the same as when the situation is reversed.

Your main question seems to have been addressed adequately in the comments, but I wanted to add these caveats so you get a fuller picture.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Events are sets of outcomes; that is why we use set operators for *intersection* and *union* to represent "and" and "or" connections between events.

The intersection of two sets is the same whichever order they sets are written. $$A\cap B=B\cap A$$

The probability measure for that intersection is thus the same.$$\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(B\cap A)$$

---

Naturally, the same argument applies for unions of events.$$\mathsf P(A\cup B)=\mathsf P(B\cup A)$$